# Creating a NSView from a CGPath

Tags: macos, nsview, appkit, cgpath

I have a CGPath and I want to draw it once to a NSView. Seems relatively simple but I haven't found a way in AppKit (non iphone).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `-drawRect:`, You use [CGContextAddPath](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000950-CH1g-CGContextAddPath) to add it to a context, and use `CGContext(Draw|Fill|Stroke)Path` to draw it. I.e. you subclass NSView, and override

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)needsDisplayInRect
{
    CGContextRef cgcontext = [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];
    CGContextAddPath(cgcontext,path); // assumes you have CGPathRef*path;
    CGContextStrokePath(cgcontext);
}
```

Then `-drawRect:` will be called whenever appropriate. You can force the view to update by calling `[view displayIfNeeded]`.

Comment: CGContextAddPath doesn't actually draw the path — you need to use CGContext{Draw|Fill|Stroke}Path for that.

Comment: Chuck is right. This is what I ended up doing. Just thought there would be a simpler way but I guess not.